# Firefox stuck on version 58 after running apt install

Tags: linux-mint, firefox

When I run

```
apt update
apt get install firefox
```

then

```
apt-cache policy firefox
```

produces

```
Installed: 61.0.1+linuxmint1+rosa
```

However if I start it with firefox in the terminal or in the start menu, and go to Help-> About Firefox, it still shows version 58.

How do I ensure I have 61?

Comment: What does `which firefox` in the terminal say? (Maybe you once installed an 58 manually and it's still first in the search path.)

Comment: /home/michael/bin/firefox, so if I did, how would I ensure the manually installed one doesn't get called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you seem to have a manually-installed firefox in `~/bin`, one step forward would be to `mv ~/bin/firefox ~/bin/firefox58`, which will leave the old version around, just in case. (Even though `firefox` is usually a shell script that redirects to `firefox-bin`, I *think* it is smart enough so that the Firefox 61 shell script shouldn't pick up the Firefox 58 `firefox-bin`.)

Comment: that did the trick, although I can't run firefox from the terminal now,  just the start menu

Comment: Make an alias for `firefox` or add the changed location to the system environment's `path` variable to run it from whereever on the system.